# logcat displaying excessive delay setting brightness

Tags: android, logcat, android-virtual-device, android-logcat

i created a simple android app in eclipse and and am running it on an emulator. its really slow and when i checked logcat i saw a couple of 'excessive delay' lines.

EDIT: to clarify, the app does run and displays the intended **'Enter a message sir'**. i was looking at why it was so slow and thought the excessive delay would have something to do with the lag.

Here are my files:

**Emulator Settings:**

```
Target: Android 4.1 - API Level 16
CPU: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
SD Card: 9MiB
Max VM application heap size: 1024
Device Ram Size: 1024
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.my.first.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my.first.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/welcome_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/welcome_message_text" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/editor_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/editor_button_text"   
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout >
```

**LOGCAT LOGS:**

```
09-24 17:26:00.363: E/PowerManagerService(158): Excessive delay setting brightness: 420ms, mask=2
09-24 17:26:00.584: E/PowerManagerService(158): Excessive delay setting brightness: 218ms, mask=2
09-24 17:26:01.602: I/Choreographer(1750): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-24 17:26:32.856: I/Choreographer(1750): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-24 17:26:52.942: E/PowerManagerService(158): Excessive delay setting brightness: 158ms, mask=2
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is running on your UI thread

Comment: @draksia how do i see the code in said UI thread?

Comment: Anything called from the methods that belong your activity

Comment: @draksia added the mainactivity.java

Comment: If you look at the process id numbers in parenthesis, you will see that the "Excessive Delay" message in (158) is from something else on the phone.  But the frame skip message in (1750) *could* be from your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an emulator on your computer, this is common and is related to the performance of your computer running the emulator and not your application.

This will still happen on occasion on a phone plugged into your computer and used as an emulator as well, but FAR less often and is rare.

Most likely your application is fine.

You can confirm this by plugging in your phone to the computer and just use the phone without your app. You'll see a number of exceptions in the logcat from the system on its own.

You can also install [Catlog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) on your phone itself and see errors reported directly on your phone without plugging it into your computer. You can see if this occurs while running your app and without running to see if there really is an issue.

*NOTE:* On Android 4.1+ Catlog requires root, but it works without on earlier 4.0 and under.